# How to get text of the span element within anchor tag?

Tags: jquery

I was just wonder about how to get the text of the span element within the anchor tag.

```html
<a class="draw-ticket-wrap">
 <span style="display: none;" class="TicketValue">1000</span>
 <span style="display: none;" class="TicketId">7</span>
  <span style="display: none;" class="TicketTotalNumberOfTickets">125</span>
  <span style="display: none;" class="TicketTitle">$1,000 Order</span>
  <span style="display: none;" class="TicketDescription"><p><strong>200 Chances to win</strong> 
              
  </a>
```

I would like to get the text of the first span element whose class name is 'TicketValue'. The entire html is a jquery object i.e $html.

Comment: Are there more than one of them on the page? Do you only need the first one? Or are you just referring to the fact that `TicketValue` is the first span within the hyperlink tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to get the text of the first span. Below uses span's class selector to select the first span. See below,

```js
$(function() {
  alert($('a.draw-ticket-wrap span.TicketValue').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="draw-ticket-wrap">
  <span style="display: none;" class="TicketValue">1000</span>
  <span style="display: none;" class="TicketId">7</span>
  <span style="display: none;" class="TicketTotalNumberOfTickets">125</span>
  <span style="display: none;" class="TicketTitle">$1,000 Order</span>
  <span style="display: none;" class="TicketDescription"><p><strong>200 Chances to win</strong> </p></span>
</a>
```

Comment: First time i've seen snippets run like this in SO - pretty rad.

Comment: @lfender6445 ikr, I love it too, I have been trying to use it where ever possible.. It is just cool.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $(".TicketValue").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way based on your criteria

```
$html.find('.TicketValue')[0].innerText
```

Comment: In solution 1 above, how about if I put it this way,  $html.find('span.TicketValue').text(); since the entire html is a jquery object.